# What is this internal plug on my HP Mellanox ConnectX-3 card near the activity LEDs?

Tags: hp, nic, mellanox

I recently bought a second-hand Mellanox ConnectX-3 card for a lab setup. There seems to be an internal connector on it near the activity LEDs, which I think might be for hooking them up to a front panel. Is that correct? It is a Mellanox × HP card, so might be an HP-specific thing. The [datasheet I could find on HPE's site for the 790314-001 Dual SFP+ card](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docLocale=en_US&docId=c04621677) is pretty useless.

Anyways, is it for panel LEDs, and if not, what is it for? What can I search for to get the mating part?

[image: Mellanox Card with white plug circled]

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the card on google, further down the list is a link to NVidia & its PDF manual. It states that it is an i2c connector. Now, what precisely it can be used for is left as an exercise to yourself.